# Return user to previous page after login (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a rails 2.3.8 site I have login links on each page (that takes a user to a separate signin page). After a successful login the user is currently redirected to root. Instead I'd like to redirect to the page they were previously viewing.

I've tried using request.referer:

```
redirect_back_or_default(request.referer)
```

Where redirect_back_or_default:

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

But that generates an "access denied" error, even though the login is successful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of trying to redirect to the referrer, I would set the session[:return_to]

You'll need a before filter that runs before your authentication on all your actions:

```
def store_return_to
  session[:return_to] = request.url
end
```

Then change your redirect to just be

```
redirect_back_or_default()
```

Answer (score 1):

Before all you must store your `url` by `cookies`:

```
cookies[:return_to_url] = request.url
```

And then after success logging:

```
redirect_to cookies[:return_to_url] || root_path
cookies[:return_to_url] = nil

# or even better code in one line:
redirect_to cookies[:return_to_url].delete || root_path
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html