# Rails 3 - Devise request.referer always has sign_in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise

I am using [devise](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/tag/devise/). I want to redirect to previous page after sign in process is successful. The problem I am having is that the request.referer always has sign_in URL in it. How can I get the URL of the previous page without some explicit hooks.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || search_index_path
end
```

Comment: Just maintain a `cookie` storing the `current_path` of the User. And use this cookie after you have successful logged in. And store the current_path cookie only if user is logged in.

Comment: Can't you use session for this? May be you can use a before_filter to store previous path.

Comment: Not sure if its helpful in your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489660/return-user-to-previous-page-after-login-rails

Comment: You are right Nadeem. I have done a little hack for this. I am saving the url in session and also using a before filter but the only check is that it will store URL if the url is not sign in or sign up. Thank you for your reply. If you can give an answer i will mark a tick to it but with the check for sign_in/sign_up url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not on my dev machine so can't verify it. But it should be.

```
#application controller

def store_return_to
      session[:return_to] = request.uri
end

def redirect_back_or_default
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || root_url)
    session[:return_to] = nil
end


#home_controller | or any other controller we want to use it.
before_filter :store_return_to

# Session/login_controlelr
Call this function after successful sign_in or sign_up
redirect_back_or_default
```

A bit off the track(devise) but will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

inside action controller put

```
before_action :store_return_to, unless: :devise_controller?
def store_return_to
 store_location_for(resource, request.url)
end
```

Where `resource` is your devise model, `:user` per example