# Rails - Devise - Redirect to current page after login or logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application and using Devise for user authentication. However, whenever I login or logout (from any page) I am always redirected to the home page "/". While what I'm trying to do is that when I login from any page (e.g. "/events") I am redirected back to this exact page ("/events" in this case) after login. And the same goes for logout.

I tried following [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/how-to:-redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update). But the output of `store_user_location` is always "/" and also, the  functions `after_sign_out_path_for` and `after_sign_out_path_for` are not overridden and my code for them was never reached.

I added `after_sign_out_path_for` also in application_controller as follows:

```
def after_sign_in_path(resource_or_scope)
    puts stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
end
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please post the code. Where did you put `after_sign_out_path_for`, etc.

Comment: @razvans I updated my question with the code for ```after_sign_out_path_for```. I added it to applicaation_controller as I'm not using customized Devise controllers (except for a part related to social media omniauth authentication)

Comment: @TamerB please try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535503/5117953

Comment: I figured out the problem. Whenever I navigate to any page, for some reason home_controller (the controller of the root path) is used after calling the page (but doesn't display in the page). Obviously it is a bug. Do you have any ideas about any possible reasons for such action?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `request.referrer` to the `sessions_controller.rb` or `application_controller.rb`

You can access referer path using `request.referer`

Like below

```
protected

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || request.referrer
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || request.referrer
end
```

See the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out#keeping-user-on-the-same-page-after-signing-out)